# How to change Windows console app C# project into Windows Service using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, service, windows-services, console-application

I used [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3938/Creating-a-C-Service-Step-by-Step-Lesson-I) to create C# Windows service using Visual Studio 2010 and its stock console app project, but after I changed everything and tried to install it as such:

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil" /i myservice.exe

I don't see my service in the list of services through Control Panel. I then checked the output from the `installutil` and found this message:

> Remove InstallState file because there are no installers.

I'm not sure why it says it because I do have an installer class, defined as such:

```
namespace MySrvr
{
    class MyServiceInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public MyServiceInstaller()
        {
            ServiceProcessInstaller process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();

            process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

            ServiceInstaller serviceAdmin = new ServiceInstaller();

            serviceAdmin.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

            serviceAdmin.ServiceName = "MyServiceName";
            serviceAdmin.DisplayName = "My Service Display Name";
            serviceAdmin.Description = "My Service Description";

            Installers.Add(process);
            Installers.Add(serviceAdmin);
        }

    }
}
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you running the `installutil` command from an administrative command prompt?

Comment: I've never seen it used with an /i parameter before.  Have you tried running it as `installutil myservice.exe`?  And is the installutil located in the same directory as myservice.exe? If not, you'll need to give the path.

Comment: @Tim: Yes, it obviously comes with a path. The `/i` is an optional parameter for `install`. But, OK. I ran it without it and still got the same result. It's almost like my installer is not compiled...

Comment: @ahmd0 - one thing I can think of is to make sure your `installUtil` and your executable file are from the same version of the .Net Framework (e.g. both are V2.0, etc).

Comment: Are you using the right version of installutil (64-bit vs 32-bit)? If your app is targeting a specific platform, you have to use the appropriate installer.

Comment: @BrendaBell: I updated the actual path to `installUtil` I'm using. The project is set up as `x86`

Comment: BTW, I still don't have this working... any other ideas, guys?

Comment: Someone above mentioned that I need to link to the .NET framework v2.0. Is it really necessary? Can I go with .NET Framework v.4.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I got it. Two errors:

1. The installer class must be declared as `public`
2. It must have `[RunInstaller(true)]` attribute in front of it.

As such:

```
namespace MySrvr
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class MyServiceInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
    }
}
```

The version of `installutil` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: +1 for figuring it out **and* sharing the solution for future users :)